# How do I resolve an external JavaScript script conflicting with a CSS file?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

The bootstrap modal function `$("#myModal").modal();` on my page used to work perfectly, until I added the external **CSS** file below in order to add animations to my page:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
```

*Read more about:* [how to animate elements on your page](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) here.

After adding the external **animation** **CSS** file above, I noticed that running `$("#myModal").modal();` opens the `#myModal` however the entire modal is hidden behind a `modal-backdrop`. This makes it impossible to interact directly with the opened modal. Meaning clickable areas like the **close** button on the modal no longer work.

Following is are two images to demonstrate the differences between running  `$("#myModal").modal();`, with and without the above **animation** CSS file.

[image: With the animation script]

The above image shows the result of running `$("#myModal").modal();` **with** the animation CSS file...

[image: Without the animation script]

...while the above image shows the result of running `$("#myModal").modal();` **without** the animation CSS file.

Find below my HTML page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the web app to work optimally (with animations and opening bootstrap modals), I need **both** external scripts/CSS files to work in tandem.

Whenever I comment out the **animation** CSS file , my bootstrap modal function `$("#myModal").modal();` goes back to working as intended.

How do I resolve this issue of two conflicting external script and CSS file?

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Did you try to load the animation CSS file FIRST, then load your bootstrap file AFTER?  If that doesn't work, you'll need to find what CSS loading in the animation CSS file is overriding your bootstrap stuff, and either re-override it, or use !important.

Comment: Use elements inspector in browser dev tools to find conflicting rules and write a more specific override rule for the modal

Comment: I just recreated a bootstrap modal with your code example and it seems to display the same way, even with animate.css included. The css and js are included in the same order you have them listed. https://codepen.io/bonniemellott/pen/gVBpWJ

Comment: @Bonnie Were you able to find any solution to this?